# Why is there a crack in my texturing, and why does it grow with distance?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I textured a bean in another platform (procreate) and exported it as an obj into blender and for some reason, there is this "crack" in my texturing that becomes more prominent with increased distance from the object. How do I fix this, and how do I prevent this in the future? I've added my blend file:

[image]

[image: close up]

[image: far away]

[image: texture]

Comment: it looks like it's a problem of painting that doesn't bleed enough around the UV islands, but you didn't share the object with its material and image texture

Comment: yes it is as moonboots has described as we can see in your UV islands https://snipboard.io/ftsacb.jpg you could make the texture bleed more over the islands but it seems like your uv unwrapping is not nicely done. next time do proper unwrapping, maybe add a seam to an area not easily seen before unwrapping.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie how would I make the texture 'bleed' around the islands? I've added my texturing to the question for reference. I definitely don't mind re-texturing if the problem is with my model, but I just need to figure out how to unwrap properly since this has happened with multiple models lol!

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using Procreate to texture, I copied the texture of the model, opened it in a new Procreate file, cut the white background out, duplicated it, added a Gaussian blur, duplicated it a ton more times so it builds a border around the islands, and finally merged the layers and copied that over to the original model.

but MAKE SURE to keep the original cut out of the islands on top so the detail doesn't get lost with the initial Gaussian blur.

Comment: Doesn't scaling down the UVs work, effectively leaving a red border around your UVs?